# Making a dynamic regression

Tags: excel, vba, regression

I am trying to make my regression analysis dynamic by using the code below, however, I keep on getting Regression-LINEST error when I run the code (see image below for error). My Y input is on column C and my X input is on column A(See image below). Maybe I did something wrong with my X and Y inputs or my columns

```
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Sheets("Holding Cost").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", Sheets("Holding Cost").Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lastRow, 3)), _
    Sheets("Holding Cost").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)), False, True, , Sheets("Holding Cost").Range("$k$2"), _
    , False, False, False, False, , False
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: For starters try adding sheet reference to every instance of Cells.

Comment: Note: If you tell us you get an error, this information is useless for us to help you unless you tell us *which* error exactly you get and *where*. Please [edit] and update your question with the missing information.

Comment: Have you tried running it manually to see if it works?

Comment: Also using column A looks a bit odd.

Answer (score 2):

`Sheets("Holding Cost").Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lastRow, 3))` will fail when "Holding Cost" is not the active sheet.

`lastRow = Sheets("Holding Cost").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` will fail when the active sheet is a sheet other than  worksheet (ie. Chart sheet).

I'm not a mathmetician, so assuming that your column references are correct, try the following instead...

```
Dim holdingCostWorksheet As Worksheet
Set holdingCostWorksheet = Worksheets("Holding Cost")

Dim lastRow As Long
With holdingCostWorksheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

With holdingCostWorksheet
    Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", .Range("C2:C" & lastRow), .Range("A2:A" & lastRow), False, True, , .Range("$k$2"), , False, False, False, False, , False
End With
```